# why this operator $T$ is always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ ordered basis for $V$

Let $T:V \to V$ linear operator  and given the representation matrix with respect to the basis $B$ $$[T]_B^B = {\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & 0 & 8 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 8 & -1 & 5 \end{array}\right]}.$$

Why is it true that $T$ is always diagonalizable?

I do not understand how I can conclude anything about eigenvector? this the only way I think on approaching this kind of question

Comment: Are you aware that real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable?

Comment: The adverb "always" is weird. If $T$ is diagonalisable, it won't suddenly become non-diagonalisable.

Comment: @neca Isn't it true only if my basis $B$ was orthonormal?

Comment: @Sagigever Yes. And also if it is *not* orthonormal.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so my conclusion from the following comments,
if I have real  symmetric matrix it will always be diagonalisable, in addition I will have an orthonormal basis that includes all the eigenvectors of my symmetric matrix?

Comment: @user1551 I am talking about the operator itself, what If I have basis $C$ such that the represent matrix with respect to $C$ is not symmetric?

Comment: The first part is correct: if the matrix is symmetric, then it is diagonalizable. Furthermore, if it is the matrix of $T$ with respect to an orthonormal basis, then there will be an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ which consists of eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: I was also talking about the operator. A linear operator is diagonalisable if and only if it has an eigenbasis. If it has an eigenbasis, it won't suddenly lose the eigenbasis.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but what if I have another basis that the represent matrix with respect to that basis is not symmetric? how can I know for sure that $T$ is diagonlisable?

Comment: If the matrix with respect to *some* basis is symmetric, then it is diagonalizable.

Comment: If we want a charcterization of the linear transformation itself, without mention of any of its matrix representations, we would say a self-adjoint linear transformation has a complete basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @hardmath this linear transformation not neccesery self adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this question in a little bit more general setting.

One of the common definitions of diagonalizability is that a linear operator $A\colon V\to V$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. The most general class of linear operators satisfying this property are the so called [normal operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator). We say that a linear operator $A$ is a normal operator if and only if it commutes with its Hermitian adjoint: $AA^*=A^*A$.

Since a linear operator on $V$ can be expressed in a matrix form we also have a notion of a [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), i.e. the matrix $A$ is normal if and only if $AA^*=A^*A$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. Note that for the real case $A^*=A^T$, so a real matrix $A$ is normal if and only if $AA^T=A^TA$. This property is invariant under the change of basis since
$$AA^T=A^TA\Longleftrightarrow P^{-1}AA^TP=P^{-1}A^TAP$$
for any invertible matrix $P$.

In this particular problem it's easy to note that $T$ is represented as a symmetric matrix in the given basis $\mathcal{B}$, i.e. $([T]_{\mathcal{B}})^T=[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$, so $T$ is normal, since $TT^T=T^2=T^TT$.